# how to hide bgcolor for mobile in Bootstrap ?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have everything working fine for my large screen. How do I hide just `bgcolor` for mobile ?

I have

```
<td bgcolor="##f5f5f5">
```

how do I put `hidden-xs` without hiding the entire row ?

Answer (score 5):

Add Id or class to your `<table>` `<td>` and target the class or Id with media Query for devices, don't use inline css for responsive design.

```
<td id="example_id" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">


 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      td#example_id {
      background-color: #f00 !important;  
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many `<td>` that you want to hide the bgcolor, give your tds a class attribute and then use the following CSS with them:

**HTML:**

```
<td class="bghidden" bgcolor="##f5f5f5">
```

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .bghidden {
  background-color: initial;  /* or background-color: transparent; */
 }
}
```